# momentjs calculates date difference incorrectly

Tags: momentjs

In my angular web application, I want to compare two dates to see if a person is less than 18 years old when she/he entered the company. Here is the code I use to do this:

```
  const dayOfBirth = moment(formControl.value, this.dateFormat, true).startOf('day');
  const entranceDateControl = this.wizardFormGroup.get('entranceDate');
  const entranceDate = moment(entranceDateControl.value, this.dateFormat, true).startOf('day');

  // Check validation rule R3: Age is less than 18 compared to entrance date
  const difference = moment.duration(Math.abs(entranceDate.diff(dayOfBirth)));
  if (difference.years() < 18) {
    const validationMessage = this.getValidationMessage('R3', formControlName);
    return validationMessage ? validationMessage.message : null;
  }
```

As you can see, I am using `startOf('day')` to get rid of any time component so that I only handle dates. I use `diff()` to get the difference between two dates and then `duration()` to convert the difference to years, months, days, etc. Using this code, the validation message should NOT show when the person is turning 18 years old on the day when she/he entered the company.

Upon testing this, I came across what is, in my opinion, strange behavior. Depending on months and years used, it gave different results. For instance, for these dates it was Ok:

```
dayOfBirth   = 1998-03-01, 1998-04-01, ..., 2000-02-01
entranceDate = 2016-03-01, 2016-04-01, ..., 2018-02-01
```

But the following dates returned the validation message:

```
dayOfBirth   = 2000-03-01, 2000-04-01, ..., 2002-02-01
entranceDate = 2018-03-01, 2000-04-01, ..., 2020-02-01
```

After these dates, i.e. using `2002-03-01` and onward, it works again. I also got wrong result for the dates preceding `1998-03-01`.

Now, I had a closer look at the Duration object and I noticed that for the times where it was less than 18 years, it had calculated 864 milliseconds **less** then when it came to the right conclusion that it was 18 years between the dates.

```
Correct duration
----------------
dayOfBirth   = 1998-03-01, 1998-04-01, ..., 2000-02-01
entranceDate = 2016-03-01, 2016-04-01, ..., 2018-02-01

Duration = 568080000000 ms

Wrong duration
--------------
dayOfBirth   = 2000-03-01, 2000-04-01, ..., 2002-02-01
entranceDate = 2018-03-01, 2000-04-01, ..., 2020-02-01

Duration = 567993600000 ms

Duration difference
-------------------
568080000000 - 567993600000 = 86400000 ms = 24 hours = 1 day
```

Has anyone an explanation for this? Can it be considered a bug in momentjs? Any viable workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't go into details in moment source code but it seems `duration()` is playing tricks with you.  Simplify the code and rely only on `diff`as follow and you should be good (at least it seems to work for the samples you provided). And it's easier on the eyes :)

```
const moment = require('moment')

const dayOfBirth = moment('2000-03-01').startOf('day');
const entranceDate = moment('2018-03-01').startOf('day');
const difference = entranceDate.diff(dayOfBirth, 'years') 

if (difference < 18) {
  console.log( '<18')
} else {
  console.log( '>=18')
}
```

will output `>=18`